# Match string only if not preceded with another

Tags: c#, regex

Here is my sample code:

```
string pattern = "(@param)(?=.*where)";
string updateQuery = @"update Table set column = @param where otherColumn = @param";
string newUpdateQuery = Regex.Replace(updateQuery, pattern , "CONVERT(NVARCHAR,'param')");
Console.WriteLine(newUpdateQuery);
string insertQuery = @"insert into Table (column) values(@param)";
string newInsertQuery =  Regex.Replace(insertQuery, pattern , "CONVERT(NVARCHAR,'param')");
Console.WriteLine(newInsertQuery);
```

output:

```
update Table set column = CONVERT(NVARCHAR,'param') where otherColumn = @param  
insert into Table (column) values(@param)
```

I want match parameter before where condition.
But in insert query,this pattern cannot match any parameter.
If add '?' in pattern like this

```
string pattern = "(@param)(?=.* where)?"
```

output will become

```
update Table set column = CONVERT(NVARCHAR,'param') where otherColumn = CONVERT(NVARCHAR,'param')
insert into Table (column) values(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,'param'))
```

This output is what I want:

```
update Table set column = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, 'param') where otherColumn = @param
insert into Table(column) values(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, 'param'))
```

If a query have where condition.
Only match param before "where"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure you only match `@param` if it is not preceded with `where`:

```
string pattern = @"(?<!\bwhere\b.*)@param";
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/C1EK8l)

**Pattern details**

- `(?<!\bwhere\b.*)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a  whole word `where` (`\b` are word boundaries) and again any 0+ chars other than a newline immediately to the left of the current position
- `@param` - a literal substring (add `\b` at the end to match as a whole word if needed).

Full C# test:

```
string pattern = @"(?<!\bwhere\b.*)@param";
string updateQuery = @"update Table set column = @param where otherColumn = @param";
string newUpdateQuery = Regex.Replace(updateQuery, pattern , "CONVERT(NVARCHAR,'param')");
Console.WriteLine(newUpdateQuery); // => update Table set column = CONVERT(NVARCHAR,'param') where otherColumn = @param
string insertQuery = @"insert into Table (column) values(@param)";
string newInsertQuery =  Regex.Replace(insertQuery, pattern , "CONVERT(NVARCHAR,'param')");
Console.WriteLine(newInsertQuery); // => insert into Table (column) values(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,'param'))
```

Comment: Why putting `^.*` in the lookbehind? Perhpas writing `@param(?<!\bwhere\b.*)` is more efficient, should be tested. (Or better, split the string at the first `where` and search the first part only.)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte  It is a remnant from my former tries when I did not get the question first. Updated.